# How to transfer iMessage texts from Mac to iPhone?

Tags: iphone, mac, messages, messages-in-icloud

I accidentally deleted some messages from my iPhone but they still appear on my Mac as I haven't enabled iCloud for messages on either device. Is there any way to transfer the old messages from my mac to my phone?

Comment: Are your old texts in iMessage / messages app or perhaps stored in some other file or format? I want to be sure you don’t lose data if I propose you enable iCloud sync on the Mac first.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can still sync them through iCloud. Try the following:

- If possible, make a Time Machine backup (no troubles expected, it's just good idea to make a backup of important info that you have only in one place);
- Enable iCloud sync for messages on Mac;
- Leave it charging and on Wi-Fi for several hours so messages could sync.
- Enable iCloud sync for messages on the phone;
- Tap "Merge" when prompted;
- Leave the phone on Wi-Fi and charging so messages could sync.

Comment: How do you enable iCloud syc for messages on the Mac?